# Somar Automaticamente conforme é digitado

Tags: javascript

Tenho 3 campos (a,b,c) que preciso somar e jogar o valor no campo (d) conforme vai sendo digitado, porem não condigo fazer sem clicar ou digitar mais alguma coisa depois do último número.
Tentei usar as funções `onkeyup` e `onkeydown`
Existe alguma forma?

```js
function id(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function calcular(el) {
  var a = id('a').value;
  var b = id('b').value;
  var c = id('c').value;

  id('d').value = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) + parseInt(c);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a" name="a" onkeyup="calcular()" onkeydown="calcular()" />
<input type="text" id="b" name="b" onkeyup="calcular()" onkeydown="calcular()" />
<input type="text" id="c" name="c" onkeyup="calcular()" onkeydown="calcular()" />

<input type="text" id="d" name="d" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: Uma opção seria iniciar todos os campos com 0 como valor; outra seria validar se o atributo `value` está definido e, quando não estiver, atribuir 0.

Comment: da uma olhada nesta função https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Anderson, iniciando como 0 funcionou perfeitamente, porem me pediram para colocar um checkbox agora no código, que quando estiver ticado, soma apenas os dois primeiros valores (a,b), caso contrario soma todos (a,b,c). Estou pensando em uma forma de verificar o checkbox também agora.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que enquanto o campo não possuir valor, o atributo `value` será `undefined`. Se tentar somar qualquer valor com `undefined` o resultado será `NaN`.

A solução é você considerar o valor zero quando o atributo não estiver definido fazendo algo como `var a = id('a').value || 0`.

```js
function id(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function calcular(el) {
  var a = id('a').value || 0;
  var b = id('b').value || 0;
  var c = id('c').value || 0;

  id('d').value = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b) + parseInt(c);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="a" value="0" name="a" onkeyup="calcular()" onkeydown="calcular()" /> +
<input type="number" id="b" value="0" name="b" onkeyup="calcular()" onkeydown="calcular()" /> +
<input type="number" id="c" value="0" name="c" onkeyup="calcular()" onkeydown="calcular()" /> =

<output id="d">0</output>
```

Outras considerações:

- Defini o atributo `value` como 0 inicialmente, pois isso ajuda na orientação do usuário;
- Alterei o tipo dos campos para `number` para usufruir de validações básicas nativas;
- Alterei o campo de resultado para `<output>` para melhorar a semântica do documento;
- Adicionei os operadores matemáticos entre os campos para melhorar a leitura;